# How to do Log in Authentication through user made Android Application?

Tags: android, authentication

How to authenticate log in page of another website using my own android application?
Can we use authentication? Ex. One time log on to 'website.com' through My Android Application

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we wants to authenticate; we need to access the valid data where from the server.
If that website/domain allow us to access or give us an interface then only we can make it live.
for that we have to get their host name and some other permissions..

I went throw all that stuff and made it true!